# Увеличение ресурсов на ВДС

Tags: vds

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При наращивании кол-ва новых сайтов следом и начала расти нагрузка на процессор в определенные часы.

На данный момент терпимо еще, но хочется знать на будущее: если говорить про увеличение ресурсов, то какие именно нужно увеличивать, чтобы снизить нагрузку на процессор : кол-во ядер , оперативная память или еще что ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В общем случае наверно ядра и архитектура процессора, но точный ответ может зависеть от точной причины возникновения нагрузки